# What am I doing incorrectly with my https request?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning how to build a RESTful api with Node and Express, and I am having an issue with this https request. I am trying to make a GET request to Scryfall's api (documentation here: https://scryfall.com/docs/api), but whenever I run my server and check the browser I get a message stating

> "localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

As I'm new to using Node and Express, I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is the code for my server.js and app.js files.

```
//server.js
const https = require('https');
const app = require('./backend/app');

const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';

app.set('port', port);
const server = https.createServer(app); //pass the express app to the server

server.listen(port);
```

and

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is the first middleware');
  next();
});

app.get('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=aust+com', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('${res.body.name} is the name of the card!');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `app.get()` does NOT make an http request.  It registers a route handler on YOUR http server so that your server can receive an http request from some client that matches the route definition you set.  So your `app.get()` is just completely wrong.  That's not how you use it and it doesn't make http requests at all.  If you want to make an http request and get the result, then it's easiest to use a library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Comment: Oh you're right! I totally forgot to add a service that will actually make the call to the API. Thank you, I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

‍ **For an example**, you can do it with this code below :

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('This is the first middleware');
  next();
});

app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/named?fuzzy=aust+com');
      res.status(200).send(result.data);
    }catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex.message);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

From the code above, you can **call the endpoint:** `localhost:3000` and than you will get the result.

I hope it's can help you .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a get request like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Expect a JSON body
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb'                   //Request size - 50MB
}));

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {

    // do whatever you need here
    res.status(200).send("ok");

});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Server is running.Point your browser to: http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```